How can i print an ASCI drawing in Python?
I'm trying to make a an if else game which has ASCI drawings, every time I paste an ASCI drawing inside the print() I keep getting errors "String literal is unterminated" and "also Expected attribute name after . "
this is the print I'm trying to use
print(",  /\  .  
 //`-||-'\\ 
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.// 
  `  ||  '  
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ()     ")

I was expecting for the axe to be printed on the console.

You can use triple quotes for multi-line strings and use raw strings, by putting "r" before the quotes, to prevent escape sequences (marked with a backslash at the beginning) from being converted.
print(r""",  /\  .  
 //`-||-'\\ 
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.// 
  `  ||  '  
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ()     """)


Ana Julía's answer is great!
I'm adding a bit for your your Y question of XY Problem.
You said you're making game, that means it's safe to assume that the same string could be called multiple times.
Having that string in middle of code, with misaligned first line is gonna be annoying.
I'd rather have newline start & end and strip before naming that string for convenience sake!
Reason why, is simple - even your ascii art's first line is missing proceeding spaces which explains itself how mistake-prone that approach is.
print(r""",  /\  .  
 //`-||-'\\ 
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.// 
  `  ||  '  
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ||     
     ()     """)

,  /\  .
 //`-||-'\\
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.//
  `  ||  '
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ()


...Which can't happen in other way because we literally can see it in complete aligned form in raw code.
# at start section of code just below imports
axe = r"""
  ,  /\  .
 //`-||-'\\
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.//
  `  ||  '
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ()
"""[1:-1]


# ... somewhere later in code
print(axe)

  ,  /\  .
 //`-||-'\\
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.//
  `  ||  '
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ()



With that sorted out, just in case if you're absolutely new to python and is having trouble designing structure - this might help, try studying how it works - at least I had fun myself!
output:
Choose a weapon:
1. Axe  - DMG: 10  / Roll check: 4
2. Bow  - DMG: 5   / Roll check: 2
>> 1

Turn 1:
Player health: 100 / Enemy health: 100
Press enter to roll the dice! (Roll check: 4)
You rolled a 2!
Attack missed!
Player attacked Enemy with 0 damage!
Enemy has 100 health remaining!

Enemy rolls the dice! (Roll check: 2)
Enemy rolled a 1!
Attack missed!
Enemy attacked Player with 0 damage!
Player has 100 health remaining!

Press enter to continue...


Turn 1:
Player health: 100 / Enemy health: 100
Press enter to roll the dice! (Roll check: 4)
You rolled a 4!
  ,  /\  .
 //`-||-'\\
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.//
  `  ||  '
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ()
Attack hit!
Player attacked Enemy with 10 damage!
Enemy has 90 health remaining!

Enemy rolls the dice! (Roll check: 2)
Enemy rolled a 3!
    (
     \
      )
##-------->
      )
     /
    (
Attack hit!
Enemy attacked Player with 6 damage!
Player has 94 health remaining!

Press enter to continue...


source:
import random
import time


# === CONFIG ===

_AXE = r"""
  ,  /\  .
 //`-||-'\\
(| -=||=- |)
 \\,-||-.//
  `  ||  '
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ||
     ()
"""[1:-1]

_BOW = r"""
    (
     \
      )
##-------->
      )
     /
    (
"""[1:-1]

# ...Preferably move above to other script/file for better management


# === UTILITY ===

def delayed_print(*args, delay=1, **kwargs):
    """Prints with a following delay"""
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    time.sleep(delay)


# === WEAPON CLASS ===

class Weapon:
    """Weapon class that calculates and show the attack result."""

    def __init__(self, name: str, damage: int, roll_check: int, ascii_art: str):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.roll_check = roll_check
        self._ascii_art = ascii_art

    def attack(self, roll_check):
        """Checks if the attack hits and print if hit. Returns damage dealt."""

        if roll_check < self.roll_check:
            delayed_print("Attack missed!")
            return 0

        print(self._ascii_art)
        delayed_print(f"Attack hit!")
        return self.damage + (roll_check - self.roll_check)


WEAPONS = [
    Weapon("Axe", 10, 4, _AXE),
    Weapon("Bow", 5, 2, _BOW),
]


def get_weapon_options():
    """Gets player's weapon choice. Returns the weapon."""

    print("Choose a weapon:")

    for i, weapon in enumerate(WEAPONS):
        print(f"{i + 1}. {weapon.name:<4} - DMG: {weapon.damage:<3} / Roll check: {weapon.roll_check}")

    choice = 0
    while choice not in range(1, len(WEAPONS) + 1):
        try:
            choice = int(input(">> "))
        except ValueError:
            continue

    return WEAPONS[choice - 1]


# === ENTITY CLASS ===

class Entity:
    """Entity class that represents a player or enemy"""

    def __init__(self, name: str, health: int, weapon: Weapon):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.weapon = weapon

    def attack(self, target: "Entity", roll_check: int):
        """Attacks the target entity."""

        damage = self.weapon.attack(roll_check)
        target.health = max(0, target.health - damage)

        delayed_print(f"{self.name} attacked {target.name} with {damage} damage!")
        delayed_print(f"{target.name} has {target.health} health remaining!")


def main():
    player = Entity("Player", 100, get_weapon_options())
    enemy = Entity("Enemy", 100, random.choice(WEAPONS))

    turn = 1

    while True:
        delayed_print(f"\nTurn {turn}:\nPlayer health: {player.health} / Enemy health: {enemy.health}")

        # player turn
        input(f"Press enter to roll the dice! (Roll check: {player.weapon.roll_check})")
        attack_check = random.randint(1, 6)

        delayed_print(f"You rolled a {attack_check}!")
        player.attack(enemy, attack_check)

        # check if enemy is dead
        if enemy.health <= 0:
            break

        # enemy turn
        delayed_print(f"\nEnemy rolls the dice! (Roll check: {enemy.weapon.roll_check})")
        attack_check = random.randint(1, 6)

        delayed_print(f"Enemy rolled a {attack_check}!")
        enemy.attack(player, attack_check)

        # check if player is dead
        if player.health <= 0:
            break

        input("\nPress enter to continue...\n")

    delayed_print("You died!" if enemy.health > 0 else "You won!")

    input("Press enter to exit...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

